# Getting “Method Not Allowed” error when POST /actuator/bus-refresh for Spring Cloud Config server when service deployed in Google Cloud

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Cloud Config Server to get the configuration from Git and I've deployed my service in google cloud.

When I run the service in my local and invoke `POST` `http://localhost:8887/actuator/bus-refresh`, it runs successfully.

But when I invoke the same for the service deployed in Google Cloud, it gives - `Request method POST not supported`,

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-05-31T13:42:56.641+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "Request method 'POST' not supported",
    "path": "/actuator/bus-refresh"
}
```

Steps I followed:

1. Installed Rabbit MQ in google cloud, exposes it as service.
2. Updated the Spring Cloud Config  -  with rabbit mq server details
3. Build and pushed docker image to GC
4. Deployed and exposes Config server in GC
5. When hitting `POST` for `http://<exyternalip>:8887/actuator/bus-refresh` getting `Request method 'POST' not supported`.
6. When hitting `GET` for `http://<exyternalip>:8887/actuator/bus-refresh` - response gives me the application.properties in git

From local by pointing to GC rabbit mq with POST, it gives success.

Below is the configuration in my Config server

```java
spring.application.name=my-config-server

server.port=8887

spring.cloud.config.server.git.skip-ssl-validation = true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=bus-refresh
spring.cloud.bus.enabled=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=****
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=****
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=****

spring.rabbitmq.host=34.68.237.224 #GC rabbit MQ
spring.rabbitmq.port=5672
spring.rabbitmq.username=rabbit
spring.rabbitmq.password=rabbit
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following dependency :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
```

instead of this :

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
```